# Geography mode distancies in GeoDjango - PostGIS 1.5

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

I store a PointField field named "coordinates" in a model.

Then, I consult nearest instances from a given one, in the command interpreter, and print its name and the distance in km.

```
[(p.name, p.distance.m) for p in Model_Name.objects.filter(
  coordinates__distance_lte=(pnt, 1000000)).distance(pnt)]
```

The thing is, when the field "coordinates" is of kind geometry, it works well. But if I include the option "geography=True", to get better precision, it returns a much smaller value, even that I am indicating to print it in km as before.

How can I get correct geography calculations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Appending .[distance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance)() to the end of the query set would result in each object in the geoqueryset being annotated with a distance object. And you can use that distance object to get distances in different units.

> Because the distance attribute is a Distance object, you can easily
>   express the value in the units of your choice. For example,
>   city.distance.mi is the distance value in miles and city.distance.km
>   is the distance value in kilometers

However in django 1.9 they [moved the goal posts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance), while appending .distance() still works, now the recommended way is to do

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
[  (p.name, p.distance.m) for p in Model_Name.objects.filter(
   coordinates__distance_lte=(pnt, 1000000)
   ).annotate(distance=Distance('point', pnt))]
```

Finally, instead of using `coordinates__distance_lte` there is a much faster method available in postgis and mysql 5.7: [dwithin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#dwithin)